# Creating user-defined keys in document

Tags: go, arangodb

I'm attempting to create a document with a user-defined key as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    driver "github.com/arangodb/go-driver"
    "github.com/arangodb/go-driver/http"
)

type doc struct {
    _key string `json:"_key"`
}

func main() {
    conn, _ := http.NewConnection(http.ConnectionConfig{
        Endpoints: []string{"http://localhost:8529"},
    })

    c, _ := driver.NewClient(driver.ClientConfig{
        Connection: conn,
        Authentication: driver.BasicAuthentication("root", "test"),
    })

    db, _ := c.CreateDatabase(nil, "dbname", nil)

    // delete the collection if it exists; then create it
    options := &driver.CreateCollectionOptions{
        KeyOptions: &driver.CollectionKeyOptions{
            AllowUserKeys: true,
        },
    }
    coll, _ := db.CreateCollection(nil, "collname", options)

    meta, _ := coll.CreateDocument(nil, doc{ _key: "mykey" })

    fmt.Printf("Created document with key '%s' in collection '%s'\n", meta.Key, coll.Name())
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Created document with key '5439648' in collection 'collname'
```

I've tried with the property of the doc type as '_key', 'key' and 'Key'. None have worked.

Comment: It will have to be `Key` for any other package (including `json`) to see it. Unexported fields will never be serialized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field needs to be visible (so uppercase) in order to be included in the JSON marshalling.

At the same time, the DB expects the JSON document to contain a `_key` attribute.

So you should specify it as:

```
type doc struct {
    Key string `json:"_key"`
}
```

Alternatively, you can try sending a `map` to the method:

```
coll.CreateDocument(nil, map[string]string{"_key": "mykey"})
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Maybe I ought to make a PR on the go-arango docs.